# Android SeekBar looks disabled when enabled

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have a weird situation. In my Android (Java) app I want to programatically disable and enable a Seekbar and this is how I do it:

```
public void disableSeekBar() {
    seek.setEnabled(false);
    seek.setClickable(false);
}

public void enableSeekBar() {
    seek.setEnabled(true);
    seek.setClickable(true);
}
```

On one device, this works perfectly - disables and enables properly. But on another device, the SeekBar works bad: I can disable this Seekbar, but when I want to enable it, it stays gray but is clickable. It looks disabled but is enabled - the functionality works but the Seekbar looks like it's disabled and is gray.
After the click it changes the look from gray to red (in my case enabled SeekBar is red) and looks like it should look like after the `enableSeekBar()` method.
Also, when I take a screenshot the SeekBar goes from gray to red.

I have no idea what may cause the problem. I googled this scenario but didn't find a similar problem.

Comment: `seek.invalidate()` makes no difference. the seekbar still doesn't change color from gray to red

Comment: Please check the logic where these two functions are called , you can use breakpoint and debug mode in android studio to make sure the order of function calls